# Using a global filter field instead of a per column filter

Tags: react-data-grid

Assessing React-data-grid, I see the filter example puts a filter field on each column.  Is it possible to implement a global filter field for the whole table?

Demo
http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/column-filtering